# Bolt 100 watt amp making a phaser noise

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, amplifiers

My Bolt amp is making this wierd noise. Sounds like a flanger or phaser when pushed hard with my OD pedals. I have never heard this noise before in any amp.

Could it be the Phase Inverter tube? The amp is fairly new, about 3-4 months old. Yes, it gets a lot of use but a noise I have never heard.

Oddly, the "tone" is still there,sounds great, but then I'll hear this wierd phasing happening, on certain note, especially the wound strings while playng lead. Very annoying, very! Phse Inverter? I hope its that easy a fix!

Comment: my amp is doing the same thing, with and without pedals. thinking maybe blown speaker......

Comment: A blown speaker or dead tube will not produce a "phaser" tone. We need some more information about this in order to properly answer it. Have you tried playing it dimed without any pedals to see if you can reproduce the issue? As horatio points out certain combinations of pedals can produce a phasey tone.

Answer (score 1):

You say "pedals" plural. Your pedals can certainly introduce cyclic elements to the tone and multiple pedals out of sync can create interesting warbling or wavering interference effects...